# Cannot upload image in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to upload photo using webdriver.Firefox in python:

```
upload_img_first = '/home/emin/Desktop/test/me.jpg'

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class, "button-class")]').send_keys(os.getcwd()+upload_img_first)
```

Red bar appears in browser bottom with image address, /home/emin/Desktop/test/me.jpg

What is wrong?

Comment: What does the html on the page look like?  It seems strange that you want to type characters in a button element.  Can you supply the page source , at least for the target element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming send_keys is being sent to the proper element, it loos like the upload_image_first variable is an absolute path.  When you send_keys, you are concatenating the current path to that absolute path.

So, if you run this program from /home/emin, you would send_keys to /home/emin/home/emin/Desktop/test/me.jpg

Comment: I forgot that path in Mac is not same as in Linux, already fixed that problem.